# Prolog return results

Tags: syntax, prolog, prolog-dif

For homework, so nothing explicit, please:

Is there a way to get Prolog to return only the *first* Goal found by the program while ignoring the other Goals that are found?

For illustrative purposes, given the program:

```
permutation([X|Xs],Zs):-permutation(Xs,Ys), insert(X,Ys,Zs).
permutation([],[]).
```

Is there a way to make the program only return the *first* permutation as its only solution? In the following case:

```
| ?- permutation([1,2,3],X).

X = [1,2,3] ? ;

X = [1,3,2] ? ;

X = [2,1,3] ? ;

X = [2,3,1] ? ;

X = [3,1,2] ? ;

X = [3,2,1] ? ;

no
```

Can we just have

```
X = [1,2,3] ?;
no
```

as the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **cut** it's the control you are looking for. Place it where you need to commit to a solution (here on toplevel, I guess). There is also the builtin **once/1**, that allows to restrict the scope of the commit 'locally' (useful for instance inside a conjunction inlined in a findall/3).

Answer (score 4):

Prolog sets choicepoints whenever an alternative branch in the search tree is possible. In order to avoid backtracking to a choicepoint and exploring such alternatives, you have to add a cut (`!/0`).

You have to check where in your program the choicepoint is set, and add the cut after that call.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to stick to the first solution is `once/1` since this keeps the effects as local as possible. Using `!/0` often has already unintended effects, since the scope of `!/0` is larger.  Let's take a very simple example: The query `( X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 )` in

```
p(X) :- ( X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ).
p(4).
```

Using `once/1` we get:

```
p1(X) :- once( ( X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ) ).
p1(4).

?- p1(X).
   X = 1
;  X = 4.
```

Using `!`, we get only a single answer:

```
p2(X) :- ( X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3 ), !.
p2(4).

?- p2(X).
   X = 1.
```

Often this is not intended.

But there is a more general problem with committing to the first solution.

```
?- p1(2).
   true.
?- dif(X,1),p1(X).
   X = 2
;  X = 4.
```

So, also 2 is now a first solution? It is for such reasons that committing must be used quite cautiously. A predicate that shows similar behavior as `p1/1` lacks steadfastness. Such a predicate cannot be understood as a relation since it changes its meaning depending on the actual query.